# Grunt CSS import and paths

Tags: css, gruntjs, minify, concatenation, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have the following setup in Grunt for the concat and minification of my projects css

```
cssmin: {
        options: {

        },
        concat: {
            files: {
                'dist/app.css': [
                    'tmp/*.css',
                    'app/theme/css/vendors/fontello.css',
                    'app/theme/js/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css',
                    'app/theme/css/styles.css',
                    'app/theme/css/media-queries.css',
                    'app/app.css'
                ]
            }
        },
        min: {
            files: [{
                src: 'dist/app.css',
                dest: 'dist/app.css'
            }]
        }
    },
```

It works fine with the exception that, as far as I can tell its removed the following import statement

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic");
```

And all 3rd party css files have relative image paths which are not resolved. I can see cssmin uses [clean css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically) which should be able to help handle these issues but after hours of searching and reading the docs I can't any clear examples or doucmentation on how to configure the above to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I used Ze Rubeus suggestion of moving my font import statement into the HTML instead (a little annoying as it means modifying a 3rd party css file). But I found the option for fixing the css paths which is

```
rebase: true,
relativeTo: './'
```

My cssmin configuration now looks like

```
cssmin: {
        options: {
            rebase: true,
            relativeTo: './'
        },
        concat: {
            files: {
                'dist/app.css': [
                    'tmp/*.css',
                    'app/theme/css/vendors/fontello.css',
                    'app/theme/js/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css',
                    'app/theme/css/styles.css',
                    'app/theme/css/media-queries.css',
                    'app/app.css'
                ]
            }
        },
        min: {
            files: [{
                src: 'dist/app.css',
                dest: 'dist/app.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

And everything is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change all you import `PATH` depend on this directory `'dist/app.css'`

And instead of `css` font import I advice you to use the HTML `link` like the following

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' type='text/css'>
```

make sure to change all url `Path's` on these directory's :

```
                    'tmp/*.css',
                    'app/theme/css/vendors/fontello.css',
                    'app/theme/js/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css',
                    'app/theme/css/styles.css',
                    'app/theme/css/media-queries.css',
                    'app/app.css'
```

depend on this `output` `'dist/app.css':` because there is no task in gruntjs who correct the import `Path` in `css` files for you !

regarding your code the `watch` task need's to be something like so :

```
   watch: {

       css: {
           files: ['tmp/*.css',
                    'app/theme/css/vendors/fontello.css',
                    'app/theme/js/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css',
                    'app/theme/css/styles.css',
                    'app/theme/css/media-queries.css',
                    'app/app.css'],
           tasks: ['concat','cssmin'],
           options: { spawn: false }
       }
   },
```

And execute this command `grunt watch` in your terminal to keep automatically tracking for changes in these files and apply these tasks .